# Is a monotonic sequence defined as ‘increasing’ or ‘non-decreasing’?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I notice 2 different definitions of Monotonic Sequences in 2 Calculus Books.

**Stewart Calculus** 9th Edition defines it as `increasing`:
[image]

**Thomas’ Calculus** 15 Edition defines it as `non-decreasing`:
[image]

Obviously the presence/absence of the `=` in the definition changes what can be considered a monotonic sequence.

So which one of those definitions is correct? Is there a reason why there are conflicting definitions in such popular textbooks?

#### Regarding duplicate:

I do see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2946697/monotonic-sequence-definition) with similar title but it seems to be asking a different question related to confusion around wording of the definition. Note the words ‘successive terms’ mentioned in that post doesnt even appear in the definitions above.

Comment: Different authors use different definitions to suit their needs. This is even more common in more advanced texts.

Comment: The definitions are not "*conflicting*", though they are indeed not the same. What Stewart calls "*monotonic*" is what Thomas probably calls "*strictly monotonic*". Neither is right or wrong, they are just the definitions that each author prefers to work with in their respective textbooks. Not all math terminology is universal, in fact a lot of it is not.

Comment: the question this has been marked a ‘duplicate’ of doesnt seem to be asking the same thing as this (even though they have similar titles).

Comment: @user1078 I have reopened it, but I still think that the [*answer* to that other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2946701/446262) also answers this question.